# I've cloned a git repository and want to access a branch off of the master branch

Tags: git

A branch was created off of a remote master repository. I've cloned the repository but can't switch to the branch that was created.

`git checkout -b myfeaturename origin/myfeaturename` doesn't work. May I ask for direction?

Comment: `git fetch --all && git checkout myfeaturename` doesn't cut the mustard?

Comment: @scrowler no because the mustard smears and the straight line in between disappears

Comment: Thank You. Will you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Fetch all the remote branches (and more like tags ...)
`git fetch --all --prune`

Print out the list of all your branches:
`git branch -a`

Then check out the desired branch that you wish to work on.

---

#### Checkout the desired branch as default branch when cloning the project

`git clone ... -branch=<branch_name>`

> `--branch <name>`
> Instead of pointing the newly created `HEAD` to the branch pointed to by the cloned repository’s `HEAD`, point to  branch instead. In a non-bare repository, this is the branch that will be checked out. `--branch` can also take tags and detaches the `HEAD` at that commit in the resulting repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b myfeaturename && git fetch origin/myfeaturename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout origin/foo -b foo
```

This tells Git to checkout the branch called `foo` from the remote `origin`, and to create a new local branch with the same name.